# Web Scraping by Elements

Tags: html, excel, vba, web, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the data from a web-page. It won't work for a website for which all the format is same like as class, tag everything. I am getting an error is "Subscript out of range" and it's highlighting on "ReDim results(1 To rowCount, 1 To numColumns)" code.

I got an answer on page: [Web Scraping by TagName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55549841/web-scraping-by-tagname?noredirect=1#comment97801463_55549841)
the code works fine for https://www.neighborhoodselfstorage.net/self-storage-ocean-city-md-88769

Now I am trying to use the same code for: https://www.stormore.net/self-storage-seattle-wa-101616#utm_source=GoogleLocal&utm_medium=WRLocal&utm_campaign=101616

Please anybody help to solve this problem.

```
Option Explicit  
Public Sub GetInfo()
Dim ws As Worksheet, html As HTMLDocument, s As String
Const URL As String = "https://www.stormore.net/self-storage-seattle-wa-101616#utm_source=GoogleLocal&utm_medium=WRLocal&utm_campaign=101616"

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set html = New HTMLDocument
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", URL, False
    .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
    .send
    s = .responseText
    html.body.innerHTML = s

    Dim headers(), results(), listings As Object, amenities As String

    headers = Array("Size", "Description", "Amenities", "Offer1", "Offer2", "RateType", "Price")
    Set listings = html.querySelectorAll(".main li[class]")

    Dim rowCount As Long, numColumns As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim icons As Object, icon As Long, amenitiesInfo(), i As Long, item As Long

    rowCount = listings.Length
    numColumns = UBound(headers) + 1

    ReDim results(1 To rowCount, 1 To numColumns)
    Dim html2 As HTMLDocument
    Set html2 = New HTMLDocument
    For item = 0 To listings.Length - 1
        r = r + 1
        html2.body.innerHTML = listings.item(item).innerHTML
        'size,description, amenities,specials offer1 offer2, rate type, price

        results(r, 1) = Trim$(html2.querySelector(".size").innerText)
        results(r, 2) = Trim$(html.querySelector(".description").innerText)
        Set icons = html2.querySelectorAll("i[title]")

        ReDim amenitiesInfo(0 To icons.Length - 1)

        For icon = 0 To icons.Length - 1
            amenitiesInfo(icon) = icons.item(icon).getAttribute("title")
        Next

        amenities = Join$(amenitiesInfo, ", ")

        results(r, 3) = amenities
        results(r, 4) = html2.querySelector(".offer1").innerText
        results(r, 5) = html2.querySelector(".offer2").innerText
        results(r, 6) = html2.querySelector(".rate-label").innerText
        results(r, 7) = html2.querySelector(".price").innerText
    Next

    ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
    ws.Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like the following.

**Initial error:**

Your initial error in part, I think, is due to the url not returning the html you see when using the same url in the browser. The content I saw did not contain these listings in the response, hence row count was 0 ; therefore, your error `subscript out of range` error on this line: `ReDim results(1 To rowCount, 1 To numColumns)`

So, url changed to:

https://www.stormore.net/self-storage-seattle-wa-101616

**Next:**

Inspecting the html, to find out how to generate the listings rows, we notice that listings are represented cleanly by `.main li.pure-g`. An additional class needs adding to the li to filter out unwanted info. We want to loop only rows containing the info of interest.

```
Set listings = html.querySelectorAll(".main li.pure-g")
```

**Finally:**

Whilst inspecting the html we notice that not all rows have all items of interest e.g. `offer1` and `offer2`, so we wrap the attempts to access some items within an `On Error Resume Next`, `On Error GoTo 0` to mask the error and output "" in that column of the output.

---

VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, html As HTMLDocument, s As String
    Const URL As String = "https://www.stormore.net/self-storage-seattle-wa-101616"

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        s = .responseText

        html.body.innerHTML = s

        Dim headers(), results(), listings As Object, amenities As String

        headers = Array("Size", "Description", "Amenities", "Offer1", "Offer2", "RateType", "Price")
        Set listings = html.querySelectorAll(".main li.pure-g")

        Dim rowCount As Long, numColumns As Long, r As Long, c As Long
        Dim icons As Object, icon As Long, amenitiesInfo(), i As Long, item As Long

        rowCount = listings.Length
        numColumns = UBound(headers) + 1

        ReDim results(1 To rowCount, 1 To numColumns)
        Dim html2 As HTMLDocument
        Set html2 = New HTMLDocument
        For item = 0 To listings.Length - 1
            r = r + 1
            html2.body.innerHTML = listings.item(item).innerHTML
            'size,description, amenities,specials offer1 offer2, rate type, price

            results(r, 1) = Trim$(html2.querySelector(".size").innerText)
            results(r, 2) = Trim$(html2.querySelector(".description").innerText)
            On Error Resume Next
            Set icons = html2.querySelectorAll("i[title]")
            ReDim amenitiesInfo(0 To icons.Length - 1)

            For icon = 0 To icons.Length - 1
                amenitiesInfo(icon) = icons.item(icon).getAttribute("title")
            Next

            amenities = Join$(amenitiesInfo, ", ")

            results(r, 3) = amenities

            results(r, 4) = html2.querySelector(".offer1").innerText
            results(r, 5) = html2.querySelector(".offer2").innerText
            On Error GoTo 0
            results(r, 6) = html2.querySelector(".rate-label").innerText
            results(r, 7) = html2.querySelector(".price").innerText
        Next

        ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        ws.Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With
End Sub
```